# Как не хардкодить пароли и учётки в коде?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, безопасность

Как не хардкодить учетные записи? Какие есть варианты решения данной проблемы?

```
pdf.HtmlOptions.LogonName = "myLogin";
pdf.HtmlOptions.LogonPassword = "myPassword";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариантов полно:

- Хранить в других файлах (всякие конфиги).
- Хранить в системе – использовать переменные окружения или реестр Винды.
- Не хранить вообще, а просить ввести это дело пользователя или передавать аргументами при запуске из консоли.

Выбирайте с учётом того, как часто нужен этот логин-пароль, как часто он меняется, насколько его нужно прятать, кто должен иметь возможность его устанавливать и т.д.

Стоит также отметить, в случае получения логина-пароля от внешнего источника (удалённый сервис или человек), их можно сохранять навсегда или на время, в файл или переменную, или разово использовать и не вообще сохранять – то есть, выбор третьего варианта рекурсивно заставляет Вас ещё раз всё обдумать и сделать обоснованный выбор.

Answer (score 3):

1. Конфигурационные файлы. Самое простое, работает везде - но всё равно в открытом виде где-то хранится логин/пароль
2. Хранилища данных, типа Azure keyvault. Реализация пляшет от платформы к платформе - но зато пароля не будет ни в одном исходнике.